# Upload file root of Angular and access

Tags: angular, angular.json

I am looking to upload a .js file `example.js` to Angular root and want to access it directly via localhost:3000/example.js

I have tried adding the file directly to root and also made changes to angular.json but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to achieve this without copying the file to assets directory.

Any config changes in Angular.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it inside your `assets` array, inside your `angular.json` file.

The file need at least to be inside your `src` folder though.

so this would be

```
src
  -- assets
  -- example.js
```

Then

```json
"assets": [
   "src/assets",
   "src/example.js"
   ...
]
```

Cheers

Comment: This works on my end